# How to tell rails to use rhtml as default template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting with rails, and first minor problem that I crossed was in the tutorial - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-views.htm . There is written that the template must be named list.rhtml, but in that case server cannot find the template. But when I renamed it to list, it works. But I'd like that the file is named list.rhtml

URL is

```
http://mydomain:3000/book/list.rhtml
```

And the error is

```
  Missing template book/list, application/list with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/mejmo/library/app/views"
```

Controller is the same as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-controllers.htm

I think it is server setting.

Comment: What version is you Rails ? Try .html, rhtml is to Ruby understand and generate the html for you.

Comment: That tutorial is from Rails 2.1, and the version of Rails you installed is probably 4.0. You'll be much better off switching to a newer tutorial. Try the [Hartl book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/‎).

Comment: @bgates: Can you please resend the link, it is broken.

Comment: That's weird. [Hartl book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org).

Comment: I see, you have strange chars there :)

Comment: The tutorial is ok, but one thing which bothers me there, it's more about writing tests than actually coding. I would rename it to RailsTest tutorial.